# Microsoft Endpoint Privilege Management Deployed with Intune

Tags: security, endpoint, intune

I am trying to deploy Endpoint privilege management via intune and for some reason it's not propagating to my laptop.

I have Version 22H2 OS build 19045.3208 (which meets requirement).  I also have allocated myself a license of endpoint privilege management, turned it on in intune and setup the setting policy as well as specified.

[image]

Why doesn't this propagates to my machine?  I've resynced, restarted multiple times and it's been 1-2 days at this point.

I do have an error in intune stating deployment status error for my policy.

Comment: There are a few things you can check:

That device is actually enrolled in Intune and receiving policies. 
Verify that the Endpoint Privilege Management policy is assigned to the correct group that your device is a part of.
Check the logs on your device to see if there are any errors related to the policy deployment. You can use the Event Viewer or the Endpoint Privilege Management logs to do this.
If the policy deployment status is showing an error, click on the error to see if there are any details or error codes that can help diagnose the issue.